# jquery Not working in Fire Fox but works in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome

I use the following function for decimal validation it was work fine in IE and Chrome.But not working in Fire Fox.If I run this code in fire fox i Cant enter any character.How to solve this?

```
   $('.decimalValidate').live('keypress', function (event) {
       var decimalval= $(this).val();
       if ((event.which > 47 && event.which < 58)) {
           return true;
       }
       if ((event.which == 8 || event.which == 46) && decimalval.indexOf('.') == -1)  {
           return true;
       }
       return false;                          
   });
```

this condition is not working in FF

```
if ((event.which == 8 || event.which == 46) && decimalval.indexOf('.') == -1)  {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Please format your code correctly.

Comment: Your code works fine on me. I use Firefox too.  http://jsfiddle.net/qmF4u/   Try checking your Firefox settings.

Comment: Don't really think this is the problem but I don't see anything else: .indexOf() is a String.prototype function, maybe decimalval is no string? Because firefox often is more strict than IE (while IE often is more illogical). And yeah like in the comments below, use on instead of live: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: @MegaNairda But backspace not support in FF but working in IE and Chrome

Comment: What exactly is your aim with that input at all? Because your "not working in FF" condition is obviously not what you actually want to check for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this **[`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on)** delegate event handler with jQuery 1.7.x, because `live()` is deprecated.

Syntax of `.on()` for delegate event is:

```
$(container).on(eventNaem, target, eventHandler)
```

Here, `container` points to any `Static-element` that don't appears to DOM dynamically.

```
$(document).on('keypress', '.decimalValidate', function(event) {

     // var decimalid = $(this).attr("id"); // I think you don't need this

    var decimalval = $(this).val(); // or this.value

    if ((event.which > 47 && event.which < 58)) {
        return true;
    }
    if ((event.which == 8 || event.which == 46) && decimalval.indexOf('.') == -1) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```

---

#### According to comment

- `backspace` is not working

You are handling with `backspace` and `delete` with following condition:

```
(event.which == 8 || event.which == 46) && decimalval.indexOf('.') == -1
```

***which set validation like that:***

if you text box contains no `.` and `backspace` or `delete` key pressed the execute code within that condition block.

Above condition will fails when you text box contains `.` and you pressed `backspace` or `delete` key and condition block will not execute any `return` statement.

---

#### How to enable `backspace` when value contains `.` (dot)

Change the condition like:

just remove `&& decimalval.indexOf('.') >= -1` from the condition

```
(event.which == 8 || event.which == 46)
```

---

### AIM: yes my aim is not enter more than one dot in the input ( by @user )

### Full code

```
$('.decimalValidate').on('keyup', function(e) {
    var decimalval = $(this).val();

    var decimalvalidate = ApplyDecimalFilter(decimalval, e);
    if (decimalvalidate == false) return false;
});



function ApplyDecimalFilter(id, event) {
    try {
        return NewDecimalFilter(id, event);
    } catch (e) {
        alert(e.message);
    }
}

function NewDecimalFilter(o, event) {
    if (o.match(/\./g) && o.match(/\./g).length > 1) {
        $(event.target).val(o.replace(/\.$/, ''))
        return false;
    }
    if ((event.which > 47 && event.which < 58) || event.which == 8 || event.which == 46) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

**[Working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/DN7zE/25/)**

Comment: @user do you try this? what is the result? can you make a fiddle?

Comment: @user He's modified the way the value of the input is obtained by bypassing the unnecessary and convoluted "get the ID of the element, then select the element using that ID" method. However, they're functionally the same code **if** your element has an ID.

Comment: One should use on instead of live anyway, because live is deprecated

Comment: @Simon Agreed, though there's no mention of that in the answer. There is, in fact, almost no explanation for the changes that were made. Posting corrected code without explaining what was wrong about their original attempt is meaningless because they won't learn anything.

Comment: @user http://jsfiddle.net/DN7zE/8 Works Fine to me on Firefox 13.0.1  Backspace works.

Comment: @user you're `backspace` is working when you have no `.` in value.

Comment: Yeah but the condition excludes backspace if there is a dot in the value, maybe that's the mistake in the original code...

Comment: @thecodeparadox yes.But how to enable the backspace when the value have(.) dot

Comment: @user not putting this condition in there ;)

Comment: @user check my answer and you'll get your answer

Comment: @thecodeparadox if give decimalval.indexOf('.') >= -1.the textbox allow to enter more than one dot(.).the decimal value have only one decimal (.) symbol.my goal is decimal validation validation for the textbox

Comment: So your aim is not to allow more than one dot in the input, finally we know ;).

Comment: @Simon yes my aim is not enter more than one dot in the input

Comment: @thecodeparadox it support the text also.How to Restrict the texts

Comment: @user this is not your question topic, you've already get out of you question topic. So you should accept this answer and make google search for what you want and you'll get your answer